# Google Api OAuth2.0 and Aspnet MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api

I must have read just about everything available on the net for a decent example of using the Google API's in ASP.Net MVC 3 or for that matter any .net web server application.

Since google strongly advises using their client libraries for OAuth 2.0 I've spent the better part of the day reading the docs looking for a sample for .net web server application.

And I've found squat (except for a number of unanswered questions on SO and elsewhere).

1. [The documentation for the WebServer applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)
2. [The documentation for the .net client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2)

What I want to do is allow authenticated users of my website to import contacts from google. ie use OAuth2.0 to access google contacts api.

So my questions are:

1. Should I even use the google client libraries for OAuth2.0 in my Asp.Net MVC 3 application.
2. Is there a decent sample I can use.
3. Can someone post a good sample.

Comment: There's a complete .NET sample for the Google Drive SDK at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet It uses the Google client library for OAuth 2.0 in a ASP.NET MVC 3 application, so it should be exactly what you are looking for, except that it integrates with the Drive API and not the Contacts API.

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino while that's true for those of us coding newbs, the drive sample project isn't really enough when it comes to getting the users contacts.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed.  I have the exact some question and I'm struggling in the exact same way.  There's a sea of confusing documentation and "helper" nuget packages.  NVM, did you ever figure this one out?  I'd love to see the code.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, I never managed to get it to work. And I simply don't understand why it was closed. The drive SDK example is practically of no use for importing contacts (or atleast was..).

Comment: I wish I could post this as an answer, but I managed to connect to Google via OAuth2 to pull a user's list of Google Contacts.  I ended up completely avoiding the various .NET libraries and I wrote the OAuth2 calls myself.  It's actually incredibly easy.  I can't post all the code, but I just followed the example in Chapter 2 of the book "Getting Started with OAuth 2.0" by Ryan Boyd.